# How to override build_query method in role_adapter rolify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I am using rolify gem for authorization. When i create a new user dynamically through UI, my users_roles (in my case role_user_map) table insert is not happening. Is there a way to override build_query method? Please, guide me with this. Thank You. `
 users_controller.rb

```
def index
    store_list = @query_stores.split(" ").join("','")
    profile_list = @profiles.map {|role| role.role_name}.join("','")
    if params[:search_by].present?
      search_by = params[:search_by]
      if current_user.admin? || current_user.radial_readonly?
        @users = User.distinct.joins('LEFT JOIN stores_users ON dim_user.user_id = stores_users.user_id')
                     .joins('LEFT JOIN stores ON stores.id = stores_users.store_id')
                     .joins('LEFT JOIN clients_users ON dim_user.user_id = clients_users.user_id')
                     .joins('LEFT JOIN clients ON clients_users.client_id = clients.id')
                     .joins(:DIM_ROLE)
                     .where('dim_user.full_name LIKE :search OR dim_user.email LIKE :search OR DIM_ROLE.role_name LIKE :search OR clients.code LIKE :search OR stores.code LIKE :search', search: "%#{search_by}%")
      else
        @users = User.distinct.joins(:store_user_assignments)
                     .joins(:stores)
                     .where("stores.code IN ('#{store_list}')")
                     .joins('LEFT JOIN clients_users ON dim_user.user_id = clients_users.user_id')
                     .joins('LEFT JOIN clients ON clients_users.client_id = clients.id')
                     .joins(:DIM_ROLE)
                     .where("DIM_ROLE.role_name IN ('#{profile_list}')")
                     .where('dim_user.full_name LIKE :search OR dim_user.email LIKE :search OR DIM_ROLE.role_name LIKE :search OR clients.code LIKE :search OR stores.code LIKE :search', search: "%#{search_by}%")
      end
    else
      if current_user.admin? || current_user.radial_readonly?
        @users = User.distinct.joins('LEFT JOIN stores_users ON dim_user.user_id = stores_users.store_id')
      else
        @users = User.distinct.joins(:store_user_assignments).joins(:DIM_ROLE).where("DIM_ROLE.role_name IN ('#{profile_list}')").joins(:stores).where("stores.code IN ('#{store_list}')")
      end
    end

    if current_user.pmt_ptl_accnt_manager?
      @users = @users.find_all {|user| !user.admin? and current_user.client_list.include? user.client_list}
    end
    # added @users_total to get the total users count before paginate
=begin
    @users_total = @users
    @users = @users.paginate(:per_page => params[:per_page] || 5, :page => params[:page])
    @users_per_page = [{"name" => "5 per page", "id" => "5"},
                       {"name" => "10 per page", "id" => "10"},
                       {"name" => "15 per page", "id" => "15"},
                       {"name" => "20 per page", "id" => "20"}]
=end
  end
```

`

Comment: Rolify does not automatically add a role to the user when it is created. Nor is that what the build_query method is supposed to accomplish - which makes this a [X&Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The `build_query` method creates a SQL where clause based on the passed arguments for querying based on the roles. You should edit the question to instead include your existing code for user creation and the desired result.

Comment: Thank You. I have updated my question. In this case, how to handle it

Comment: You are still missing a comprehensible description of what it is that you are actually attempting to achieve.

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (OCIError: ORA-00904: "ROLE_USER_MAP"."ROLE_ID": invalid identifier: SELECT "DIM_ROLE".* FROM "DIM_ROLE" INNER JOIN "ROLE_USER_MAP" ON "DIM_ROLE"."ROLE_NAME" = "ROLE_USER_MAP"."ROLE_ID" WHERE "ROLE_USER_MAP"."USER_ID" = :a1 AND (((DIM_ROLE.role_name = 'super_administrator') AND (DIM_ROLE.resource_type IS NULL) AND (DIM_ROLE.resource_id IS NULL)))): This is the error i am getting when i use has_role? method